# JAR resource inputstream does not read requested size

Tags: java

I run the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InputStream stream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("resources/fonts/calibri.texture");
    try {
        int n = 458343;
        byte[] a = new byte[n];
        int i;
        do {
            i = stream.read(a);
            System.out.println("request: " + n + ", read: " + i);
        } while(i != -1);
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

in Netbeans, output is:

```
request: 458343, read: 458343
request: 458343, read: -1
```

with command `java -jar my_jar.jar` is:

```
request: 458343, read: 50563
request: 458343, read: 47392
request: 458343, read: 52704
request: 458343, read: 48790
request: 458343, read: 48714
request: 458343, read: 48903
request: 458343, read: 63921
request: 458343, read: 47532
request: 458343, read: 49824
request: 458343, read: -1
```

Both sizes, sum to 458343, but why InputStream from a resource inside JAR has such a behavior?

Comment: Why not? Where does it say it should fill the buffer?

Comment: InputStream.readNBytes​()

Comment: There is no such method, and even if there was you aren't calling it. What are you talking about?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#readNBytes-byte:A-int-int-

Answer (score 2):

The resource in the jar needs to be decompressed to be used, this is probably why the resource is returned in smaller chunks than a more efficient direct file system call. Block size may also be a factor here.